# Hibernate one to zero or one mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to map a one to "zero or one" relationship in Hibernate.  I think I may have found a way using a many-to-one.

```
class A {
  private B b;
  // ... getters and setters
}

class B {
  private A a;
}
```

Class A's mapping specifies:

```
<many-to-one name="b" class="B" 
insert="false" update="false" 
column="id" unique="true"/>
```

and Class B's mapping specifies:

```
<one-to-one name="a" class="A" constrained="true"/>
```

What I would like is for b to be null when no matching row for B was found in the database.  So I can do this (in class A):

```
if (b == null)
```

However, it seems that b is never null.

What can I do about this?

Comment: im looking forward for an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer was to add not-found="ignore" to the many-to-one statement in A:

```
<many-to-one name="b" class="B" not-found="ignore" insert="false" update="false" column="id" unique="true"/>
```

I tried simply adding lazy="false" to B as Rob H recommended, but that resulted in a HibernateObjectRetrievalFailureException everytime I loaded an A that had no B.

See this thread for more information:

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2269784&sid=5e1cba6e2698ba4a548288bd2fd3ca4e

Comment: How to have this using annotations ?

Comment: getting "incorrect number of columns" exception from this :(

Comment: NOTE:  if your other table has multiple pk's, you must define it like this: `<many-to-one name="b" class="B" not-found="ignore" insert="false" update="false" unique="true"> <column name="id" not-null="true">
<column name="pkNumberTwo" not-null="true"> </many-to-one>`

where "id" and "pkNumberTwo" are columns that must exist in the first table as well as the second. I ended up needing to remove the second PK from the second table entirely, and just use "UNIQUE" instead in my create table script, since it didn't exist in my first table and didn't really need to.

Answer (score 21):

Like Boden said, the answer is to add `not-found="ignore"` to the many-to-one statement in A. Doing this with annotation:

In Class A:

```
@ManyToOne
@Cascade({ CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinColumn(name = "Id")
@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private B b
```

in Class B:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "myForeignGenerator")
@org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(
    name = "myForeignGenerator",
    strategy = "foreign",
    parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "a")
)
private Long subscriberId;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="b")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private A a;
```

Comment: Is it also posible on many to one relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting lazy="false" on the many-to-one element. That should force Hibernate to try to fetch the association ("B") when the first object ("A") is loaded. The property in "A" will either be initialized with a real instance of "B" or null.