# Hibernate one to zero or one mapping. Exception: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, persistence

I do as @Tony answered in [Hibernate one to zero or one mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841354/hibernate-one-to-zero-or-one-mapping).

I have a class `FileMeta`.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DISCRIMINATOR", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 30)
@DiscriminatorValue("FileMeta")
public class FileMeta {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected long id;

    ...SOME ATTRIBUTES...

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_GARBAGE")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    protected Garbage garbage;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private FileT type;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_SHARE")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private Share share;

    ...METHODS...
}
```

And a class `Share`.

```
@Entity
public class Share {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "shareForeignGenerator")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "shareForeignGenerator",
            strategy =  "foreign",
            parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "fileMeta")
    )
    private Long id;

    ...SOME ATTRIBUTES...

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "share")
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private FileMeta fileMeta;

    ...METHODS...
}
```

And when I tried to fill my `FileMeta` with `Share`:

```
    Share share = new Share();
    share.setFileMeta(fileMeta);
    fileMeta.setShare(share);
    fileMetaRepository.save(fileMeta);
```

I received exception: `attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property`

I followed into `Hibernate`. And noticed that, in `generator` method, the `associatedObject` is not my given `Share` object at all, but a new `Share` object instantiated by a `EventSource`

In `DefaultMergeEventListener.java`,

```
    if ( copyCache.containsKey( entity ) ) {
        persister.setIdentifier( copyCache.get( entity ), id, source );
    }
    else {
        ( (MergeContext) copyCache ).put( entity, source.instantiate( persister, id ), true ); //before cascade!
    }
```

The `copyCache` sensed that `entity` (i.e my given `Share` object) is not in `copyCache`, and instantiated a new `Share` object, which doesn't have a `FileMeta` reference obviously.

I've completely confused.

Comment: What are you trying to do here "And when I tried to fill my FileMeta with Share" ? It looks ambiguous.

Comment: I mean `fileMeta.setShare(share);`. Also I mean filling in `FK_SHARE` of a row in my `file_meta` table as soon as inserting a row in `share` table.

Comment: How can both sides of the `FileMeta <-> Share` relationship be to-one? If the forward mapping is many-to-one, the inverse mapping must be one-to-many

Comment: @crizzis . Refer to this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841354/hibernate-one-to-zero-or-one-mapping). It looks like many have managed to implement `one to zero or one` through this forward mapping being `many-to-one` while inverse being `one-to-one` method.

Comment: OK, I'm not sure I see the point of that, as `one-to-one` is by default `optional`

Comment: @crizzis Some `FileMeta`s are  not shared, so `FK_SHARE` is null. And some are not deleted, so `FK_GARBAGE` is null. This is my motivation. And this one-to-zero/one mapping is helpful.

Comment: I understand that. As I said, `one-to-one` is by default `optional`, meaning `null` is a valid value for both `FileMeta.share` and `FileMeta.garbage`. Could you explain why a simple `one-to-one` is not working in your case?

Comment: @crizzis I gave it a try. You're definitely right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The solution was mentioned in the comments to the question. It's given below for convenience.*

You can use `@OneToOne(optional = true)` or simply `@OneToOne` since default value of `optional` is `true`.

If you want to enforce 1 to 1 relationship, specify `@OneToOne(optional = false)`.